# How to wait for my remote script complete , which is triggered by paramiko module

Tags: python, multithreading, paramiko

I was trying to execute a python script in my remote machine
The remote command will take 1 minute to complete [ it is a python script, just print something in a loop]

I am seeing my thread throws the command and come out immediately.
I want my thread to wait till it  the remote script completes.

is there a way for this?

```
class Thread_cls(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self,tid,tname,ip,script):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    print 'kkk'
    self.thread_id=tid
    self.thread_name=tname
    self.ip=ip
    self.script=script
def run(self):

    print "ENTERED HERE"
    stdin,stdout,stderr=self.connect_to_linux_vm(self.ip).exec_command(self.script)
    exit_status = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
    print "out of ssh command"
    #pass
def connect_to_linux_vm(self,ip,uname=None,password=None):
    ssh_linux = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_linux.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    ssh_linux.connect(ip, username=uname,
            password=pwd)

    return ssh_linux



obj1=Thread_cls(1,'T1','x.x.x.x',"python TEST.py")
obj1.start()
obj1.join()
```

Comment: plz consider accepting the answer if you believe it solved your question.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed it. Done!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = self.connect_to_linux_vm(self.ip).exec_command(self.script)
```

to two lines:

```
ssh = self.connect_to_linux_vm(self.ip)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(self.script)
```

otherwise the `SSHClient` object returned from `connect_to_linux_vm()` would be immediately destroyed after it invokes `exec_command()` since there's no other vars still referenceing to it.

Comment: Worked!! Thanks Buddy!!